# kbdrate on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: keyboard, hyper-v

I'm trying to increase the keyboard delay with

```
sudo kbdrate -d 12
```

but it returns

> kbdrate: Failed waiting for kbd controller!

Also, how do I query the current value of the keyboard rate and delay?